# Merging two tiff image using c#.net

Tags: c#, image-processing, tiff

In my scenario i have two tiff image in different location say

`c:/temp/img1.tiff` and `x:/temp/img2.tiff`.

I need to merge these images as a single image programatically

suggest some ideas/codes.

Thanks,

Dev

Comment: merge how? join horizontally/vertically?

Comment: i have to join one by one (vertically).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398388/convert-bitmaps-to-one-multipage-tiff-image-in-net-2-0

Answer (score 3):

To do this using just the Framework classes, you basically do this:

1. Load each of your TIFF images into a Bitmap object, e.g. using `Image.FromFile`.
2. Save the first page with an encoder parameter `Encoder.SaveFlag` = `EncoderValue.MultiFrame`
3. Save each subsequent page to the same file with an encoder parameter of `Encoder.SaveFlag` = `EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage` using `Bitmap.SaveAdd`()

It would look something like this:

```
ImageCodecInfo tiff = null;
foreach ( ImageCodecInfo codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders() )
{
    if ( codec.MimeType == "image/tiff" )
    {
        tiff = codec;
        break;
    }
}

Encoder encoder = Encoder.SaveFlag;
EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParamters(1);
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

bitmap1.Save(newFileName, tiff, parameters);

parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
bitmap2.SaveAdd(newFileName, tiff, paramters);

parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
bitmap2.SaveAdd(parameters);
```

Comment: I will also add that my company long ago decided to purchase a toolkit (in our case, we use LEADTools) that uses unmanaged GDI for this type of thing, as GDI+ is not exactly the fastest-performing part of the Framework, and the code gets tedious. Depending on your budgetary limitations, you might want to look into that.

Comment: the 'Image' class does not have a method 'SaveAdd' that takes a string.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple ways to "merge" images. Here's a couple in pseudocode:

```
var NewImage = new Image();

ForEach (curPixel in img1)
{
   var newColor = new Color();
   newColor.RGB = (Pixel.Color.RGB + img2.PixelAt(curPixel.Location).Color.RGB) / 2
   NewImage.PixelAt(curPixel.Location) = new Pixel(newColor);
}

///OR    

int objCounter = 0;
ForEach (curPixel in Image)
{
   if(objCounter % 2 == 0){
      NewImage.PixelAt(curPixel.Location) = img1.PixelAt(curPixel.Location);
   } else {
      NewImage.PixelAt(curPixel.Location) = img2.PixelAt(curPixel.Location);
   }
}
```