# Combining memory stream and convert to file in C#

Tags: .net, compression, filestream, memorystream

I have a multipage TIFF file, and each page of this will be extracted in to memorystream passed to another method as a collection of stream. At the receiving end is it possible to combine these streams and convert it as a TIFF file itself. When I tried to convert the file in to a byte[] array and after compression,when created as a TIFF again, the file gets corrupted. Is there any way to achieve this (combining multiple streams and converting to a file).

Comment: I think a multipage TIFF file does not exist simply of `[pagedata][pagedata][pagedata]`, but more like `[header describing pages][pagedata][pagedata][pagedata]`. You'll probably need to write a valid container/header, as you can't just concatenate the bitmap data. Can't you use a library?

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there any ready to use library available for that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398388/convert-bitmaps-to-one-multipage-tiff-image-in-net-2-0 for example. Don't know of any libraries with this capability, but if they exist they shouldn't be hard to find.