# convert Linq expression C# to vb

Tags: vb.net, image, linq, bitmap, codec

hi I´m trying to implement this code: [convert-bitmaps-to-one-multipage-tiff-image-in-net-2-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398388/convert-bitmaps-to-one-multipage-tiff-image-in-net-2-0)

the Second Answer

```
ImageCodecInfo encoderInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(i =>    i.MimeType == "image/tiff";
```

my convertion in vb .net is:

```
Dim encoderInfo As ImageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(Function(i) i => i.MimeType = "image/tiff")
```

it shows me "the operator '=>' is not defined for imageCodeInfo types and string"

any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB Lambda expressions do not use `=>`.  Remove that.