# Create Tiff File from multiple BitmapImage

Tags: c#, bitmap, uwp, windows-10-universal, tiff

**Background:**

I'm developing Win 10 Universal App, have list of BitmapImage:

`List<BitmapImage> ImagesList = new List<BitmapImage>();`

Each list item is created by converting `byte[]` to `BitmapImage` by this code:

```
 public async Task<BitmapImage> GetBitmapImage(byte[] array)
        {
            using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
                {
                    writer.WriteBytes(array);
                    await writer.StoreAsync();
                }
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                List<BitmapImage> ImagesList = new List<BitmapImage>();
                await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                return image;
            }
        }
```

### Question:

*How to convert this list to single multi-page Tiff file?*

### Notes:

I've found many related answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398388/convert-bitmaps-to-one-multipage-tiff-image-in-net-2-0) but all are based on `System.Drawing` library which is not supported in Windows 10 Universal Apps, so as you can see in my code, I'm using `Windows.Ui.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` object instead of `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to get the image.

Comment: would like to know what solution you went with please

Comment: I believe I used the answer below, but can't confirm currently coz I don't have access to source code anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to convert this list to single multi-page Tiff file

In UWP app, we can use [`BitmapEncoder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) to encode a Tiff image file to contain several frames. [`BitmapEncoder.SetPixelData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.setpixeldata.aspx) method can be used for setting pixel data on one frame and then [`BitmapEncoder.GoToNextFrameAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.gotonextframeasync) can  asynchronously commits the current frame data and appends a new empty frame to be edited. So the Tiff image can be created by multiply images.

Suppose I want to create a Tiff image file from three images that are located on my local folder, I decode and read pixel data from them and set to the Tiff image. Sample code as follows:

```
 private async void btnConvert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     StorageFolder localfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
     StorageFile image1 = await localfolder.GetFileAsync("caffe1.jpg");
     StorageFile image2 = await localfolder.GetFileAsync("caffe2.jpg");
     StorageFile image3 = await localfolder.GetFileAsync("caffe3.jpg");
     StorageFile targettiff = await localfolder.CreateFileAsync("temp.tiff", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
     WriteableBitmap writeableimage1;
     WriteableBitmap writeableimage2;
     WriteableBitmap writeableimage3;
     using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await image1.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
     {
         SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap;
         BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
         softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
         writeableimage1 = new WriteableBitmap(softwareBitmap.PixelWidth, softwareBitmap.PixelHeight);
         writeableimage1.SetSource(stream);
     }
     using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await image2.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
     {
         SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap;
         BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
         softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
         writeableimage2 = new WriteableBitmap(softwareBitmap.PixelWidth, softwareBitmap.PixelHeight);
         writeableimage2.SetSource(stream);
     }
     using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await image3.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
     {
         SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap;
         BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
         softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
         writeableimage3 = new WriteableBitmap(softwareBitmap.PixelWidth, softwareBitmap.PixelHeight);
         writeableimage3.SetSource(stream);
     }

     using (IRandomAccessStream ras = await targettiff.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite, StorageOpenOptions.None))
     {
         BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.TiffEncoderId, ras);
         var stream = writeableimage1.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
         await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

         var stream2 = writeableimage2.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
         byte[] buffer2 = new byte[stream2.Length];
         await stream2.ReadAsync(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length);

         var stream3 = writeableimage3.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
         byte[] buffer3 = new byte[stream3.Length];
         await stream3.ReadAsync(buffer3, 0, buffer3.Length);


         encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)writeableimage1.PixelWidth, (uint)writeableimage1.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, buffer);
         await encoder.GoToNextFrameAsync();
         encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)writeableimage2.PixelWidth, (uint)writeableimage2.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, buffer2);
         await encoder.GoToNextFrameAsync();
         encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)writeableimage3.PixelWidth, (uint)writeableimage3.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, buffer3);
         await encoder.FlushAsync();
     }
 }
```

The `temp.tiff` will be created successfully. I'm not sure how you got the image byte array, but [BitmapImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) cannot be directly written to or updated, you need to got [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) object from your byte array. If you don't know how to get the `WriteableBitmap` please try to reference the following code or save the `BitmapImage` to local folder and using the code I provided above.

```
public async Task<WriteableBitmap> SaveToImageSource(byte[] imageBuffer)
{             
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
    {
        var ras = stream.AsRandomAccessStream();
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(BitmapDecoder.JpegDecoderId, ras);
        var provider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
        byte[] buffer = provider.DetachPixelData();
        WriteableBitmap ablebitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
        await ablebitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream().WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        return ablebitmap;
    }           
}
```

More details please reference the [official sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/0f5d56ae-5e57-48e1-9cd9-993115b027b9).